# Per-Tag User Histograms

Tags: feature-request, tags, users

Can you add histograms showing various stats by tag to user profile pages?

I would recommend showing total score, number of answers, percentage of answers that were accepted, or number of downvotes by tag, either for the 5-10 most active tags for that user or whichever tags you select.

This would give a rather idea of the user's skill level in specific areas, and would be very helpful for Careers.

It would also be interesting to allow a date filter to see what areas a user has learned and how long it took to learn them.

It would also help track silver/gold tag badges

Comment: +1 for this question: more user profile statistics would be welcome (as they are addictive ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I added some [per-user statistics](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/users/) to my [SO stats pages](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/). Currently I've only run this for 10k+ users, but it shows a bunch of user stats per user and for each user, per tag.

Comment: I don't seem to understand the "Answers" column. I can't reconcile my SO profile which says 615 answer today, to the 1889 from your data. but I do often edit my answers to provide progressively better responses. It is possible you;re counting each edit separately? Very cool stuff, in any case.

Comment: It seems that the rep-points that a user has, is roughly related to how many answers they have. So I would like to see a scatter plot of rep vs number of answers.

Comment: Nice! Shame I only have 6608 rep on stackoverflow ;-)

Comment: @dmckee: Hmm, it looks like I forgot to sanity check the data. I'll work on that later today and update here when I've got it sorted. :)

Comment: @dmckee: Ok, the totals page is now correct (it was just a bug in the rollup, the per-user pages weren't affected).

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: could you re-run this please (I've just crossed the 10k mark and would be interested in seeing my own stats). Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ChristopheD: I just re-ran it for the April data dump. However, your reputation was 9850 at that time.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Ok, thanks! (guess i'll have to be patient ;-)

Comment: @GregHewgill You need to check that URL, as it is returning this: *The requested URL /~greg/stackoverflow/users/ was not found on this server.* May I suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill ? I could have edited it for you, but was uncertain about your preferences, and didn't feel right about taking such liberties. Just a friendly FYI.

Comment: @FeralOink: I've fixed the link, thanks for the note.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: do you re-run these from time to time? Looks outdated.

Comment: @ChristopheD: I regenerate the statistics whenever there is a new public data dump. The most recent data dump was December 2011.

Comment: @GregHewgill: thanks for letting me know!