# Chart: Statistics (views, votes, favorites) versus time and revisions

Tags: feature-request, questions, voting, bookmarks, views

## Context

I love statistics and charts.

## Feature request

I would like to have a view of the evolution of my questions.

I thought about three data:

1. **the number of views**
2. **the number of votes**
3. **the number of favorites**

The idea would be to see the evolution of these three data versus time for each question.

Another good idea would be **to show all revisions** (with a link to each) showing the impact (or not) of each revision on the 3 data.

## Demo

It's late, a picture is worth 1000 words.

An idea of this chart (I'm not graphic designer):

[image]

Comment: we do not store views over time, the other two you could graph on data.se

Comment: [More chart requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35805/per-tag-user-histograms)